# How to pass Excel data to MongoDB with Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, mongodb, parsing

I need to pass data from the Excel file to MongoDB table via Python code.
My Excel file looks like that:

| Name | Age | Subjects |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 12 | Math | Physics | Biology |
| Mag | 67 | Chemistry |  | History |

MongoDB output should look like that:

--1 object--:
Name: Alex
Age: 12
Subjects: Math, Physics, Biology

--2 object--:
Name: Mag
Age: 67
Subjects: Chemistry, History

I wrote code like this:

```
import csv
import pymongo
import pandas as pd
read_file = pd.read_excel("T1.xls")
read_file.to_csv("Test.csv",
                  index=None,
                  header=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("Test.csv"))

connection = pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.0.1:27017')
db = connection.test
collection = db.table1
table = open('Test.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.DictReader(table)
collection.drop()
header = df.head()

for each in reader:
    row = {}
    for field in header:
        row[field] = each[field]
    collection.insert_one(row)
```

However, I have 2 issues with it:

1. The step with converting .xslx file to .csv is unnecessary
2. As a result, I have 2 more unwanted columns as Unnamed: 3, Unnamed: 4 with the names of other subjects, in other words, this code separates subjects in single column, because in my Excel file I have 'Subjects' as united cells

Could anybody help me with these points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `read_excel` directly gives you a DataFrame, so no need to convert it to a CSV

```
df = pd.read_excel("T1.xls")
```

2. You can create a column `Subjects` witch is a list containing all the subjects

```
df['Subjects'] = df[["Subjects", "Unnamed: 3", "Unnamed: 4"]].values.tolist()
```